jupyter notebook - Log Console on a dependent python file
In Jupyter Notebook, how can I log on the log console (shown in View -> Show Log Console) the output of some log from a Python file dependency?
In myNoteBook.ipynb file I have:
import myfile
myfile.test()

In myfile.py I have
def test():
  print('Hello')

How can I see "Hello" in the Log Console when I run myNoteBook.ipynb?

Thank you @Wayne . I crosspost because some people are at one platform and not on another

For those interested, the answer is HERE
